# setState() is not updating state in setTimeout on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

```
componentWillMount(){  
    var _this=this;    
    this.setState({status1:'changed'});  
    setTimeout(()=> _this.setState({status2:'changed'}),2000);  
}
render(){
   console.log('state object',this.state);
   return(
       <div></div>
   );
}
```

on client side it works, but on server side (using express) it will only update the status1 from 'default' to 'changed' but status2 shows 'default'. how to update state in setTimeout on server side.

Comment: Side note: No need for the `var _this = this;` thing with an arrow function.

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem client-side? If so, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (If I just [copy that code into a jsFiddle and add relevant stuff](https://jsfiddle.net/7gpn5jva/), I can't replicate the problem client-side.)

Comment: working fine on client side it update both status1 and status2 but on server side it fails to update status2 in setTimeout

Comment: You will be geting two outputs in the console. First should be 'state object status1: changed, status2: default' and second  'state object status1: changed, status2: changed'. Can you check

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it only works on client side but i want the same response for server side too.. status2 is not getting update by the server

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
componentWillMount(){  
    this.setState({status1:'changed'});  
    setTimeout( () => {this.setState({status2:'changed'})},2000);  
}
```

Comment: same result .. not updating

Comment: So it seems that setTimeout will not work on server-side, since it is "part of the BOM (Browser Object Model)". I'm not sure what they were discussing here https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/249 but it seems that they had the same issue, though

Comment: i thought the same too, but the timer functions within Node.js implement a similar API as the timers API provided by Web Browsers and there is no need to call require('timers') to use the API. [link](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) ... even when i replace setTimout with something else like an ajax call the output is same, no change in state